# Create threads in ASP.NET call that preserve the HTTP Context

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis, thread-safety

I have an ASP.NET ASPX page that takes and returns XML.

Some of the types of request that this file can handle involve doing some tasks that communicate with external servers in parallel and then aggregating the results. It does this by creating new threads to perform this work and passing the HTTP context to each.

It turns out the HTTP context isn't thread safe and always comes through as NULL in each thread. The context is needed for caching XSLT objects so that each thread in each request doesn't need to read from the disk each time. The caching has never actually worked.

I'm looking to make this work either by doing the threading different, passing some form of the context that will work or change the worker code to cache in a different way.

I'm not sure which way of fixing this would be most appropriate or the best way to do any one of these. Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance of your own context Type with the context to be shared between the worker threads.

I assume you would then want to share that context object with a particular session: you could do this in one of several ways:

- Store it in a static collection with a key that is unique for each session.
- Store it in Session.
- Store it in the ASP.NET Cache with a key that is unique for each session.

Without more information on what you're trying to achieve it's difficult to advise what's best.